# openjdk-11-jre-headless installation problem on ubuntu 18.4

Tags: 18.04, apt, java, dependencies

I am trying to install openjdk-11-jre-headless or default-jre on my ubuntu machine but no mather what I do I get some error messages while doing it.

```
" The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-11-jre-headless : Depends: initscripts but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages " 

" The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre : Depends: default-jre-headless (= 2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: openjdk-11-jre but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. "
```

I have tried already these commands to fix the problem but no luck..

- sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get clean
- sudo apt-get autoremove
- sudo dpkg reconfigure -a
- sudo apt install -f

I tried the same thing with aptitude:

- aptitude install default-jre but no luck...

Any ideas how to fix the " broken package " and dependency issuses?

**Detailed system information**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

**Apt-update:**

```
- Hit:1 example/packages/live/example bionic InRelease 
- Hit:2 ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
- Hit:3 ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease 
- Hit:4 ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease 
- Hit:5 ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease 
- Hit:6 ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu trusty InRelease 
- Hit:7 ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease 
- Hit:8 adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb bionic InRelease
```

- take note -example is a valid repo i chose to rename–

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... 
Done All packages are up to date.
```

**Screenshot of apt-cache policy:**

- apt-cache policy default-jre
- apt-cache policy default-jre-headless
- apt-cache policy openjdk-11-jre

[image: apt-cache-policy-results]

Comment: I also tried apt-get install -f but no luck :/

Comment: Please add the output of `apt update`.

Comment: Hit:1 http://example/packages/live/example bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:8 https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb bionic InRelease

take note - example is a valid repo i had to change

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

Comment: Please use [edit] to add additional info.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about it.

Comment: Can you include `apt-cache policy` of `default-jre` and `default-jre-headless` and `openjdk-11-jre`. Use `apt-cache policy <package_name>`

Comment: I added them to the: apt-cache-policy-results.

Could not send straightforward copy paste because of the rep points needes :/

Comment: Thanks for the outputs, lemme see. Can you provide the output of `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre`.

Comment: Also, the output of `sudo apt install initscripts`.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem was caused:**

Some  the apt repositories contained outdated repositories not needed for the server and software anymore. They caused conflict.

Removing these repos from /etc/apt/sources.d/ repo.list file:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

After the removal the installation of default-jre and openjdk-11-headless was successful

Answer (score 0):

Only this worked for me:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo software-properties-gtk

and than apt update
sudo apt install default-jre
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "\<hold$
```

If anything comes back as held fix the hold and try the install again

Comment: Hey. Thanks for helping. I tried to find hold packages but there were none.